# How to set a color to a group border in SVG file

Tags: svg

How to outline a path group with a border color in the SVG below ? I mean a border following the external path, not just a rectangle.

[Source](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/cartes-des-regions-et-departements-issus-d-openstreetmap/)

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" width="800" height="555" viewBox="0 0 800 555" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
<style>
    svg {
        fill: white;
    }
    .region1 { 
        fill: #666666;
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 0.1;
    }
    .region1:hover {
        fill: green;
    }
    .region2 { 
        fill: #999999;
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 0.1;
    }
    .region2:hover {
        fill: blue;
    }
    .department {
        stroke: #000000;
        stroke-width: 0.1;
    }
    .department:hover {
        fill: #ff0000;
    }
</style>
<g id="region1" class="region1">
    <path class=" department" d="M 431.7125 79.1971 433.1229 77.8541 435.0823 78.0637 437.663 77.8077 438.8378 79.262 440.0246 78.7682 442.2376 79.7664 439.6917 82.4951 436.8325 83.2493 434.9637 84.5372 432.9899 83.2169 433.464 81.1324 431.8103 79.5189 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 441.3122 59.4649 443.7089 59.0262 445.6538 59.4816 447.294 59.3722 449.0975 59.2846 450.6278 60.8299 450.6503 61 450.595 61.157 449.8311 62.3451 448.6376 63.7601 446.8562 65.1029 445.3304 64.5009 443.4412 63.8324 442.6732 62.45 442.1075 60.5344 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 448.9511 77.4542 450.2825 75.9436 451.7467 73.9795 454.4525 74.1674 458.5666 75.4377 458.696 76.4699 458.9551 78.4316 458.2943 80.2502 456.524 79.1304 454.343 78.4503 453.2395 78.5962 450.4448 77.4805 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 419.3043 70.2499 420.4206 68.8181 421.172 66.6297 421.7462 65.5137 423.4464 66.0551 425.5509 65.9081 426.899 66.2916 427.1837 68.1773 426.3268 69.5834 425.6645 71.1564 424.0246 71.8746 421.483 72.3857 421.1423 71.242 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 429.8601 49.8007 431.2832 49.38 433.308 48.9671 435.7741 49.4542 437.3232 50.8907 437.6882 53.715 437.0394 55.6752 435.287 56.0764 433.7583 55.886 432.299 54.8168 431.0288 53.8662 430.7273 52.4647 429.8884 50.4881 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 428.7587 58.6016 430.8113 57.5836 432.8006 56.4813 434.3948 55.6763 436.1936 56.1884 436.9657 57.0983 436.7587 59.096 435.4791 60.313 434.4717 62.3405 432.6329 63.5709 430.7846 62.6067 429.5119 61.6103 428.6659 60.3695 428.9947 58.7651 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 434.2507 63.1033 435.1957 61.151 436.3277 59.1448 437.4569 58.2699 439.4569 59.1302 441.2677 59.8236 442.421 60.8305 442.8304 62.5844 442.2067 63.9652 440.8169 65.28 439.9639 64.9481 438.5747 63.7987 437.3096 65.8152 435.3749 66.1777 434.9875 64.8854 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 435.3607 25.379 437.236 25.7995 437.3409 27.3467 437.039 29.3334 435.3831 29.9571 433.7043 29.9662 433.3766 27.7234 434.5072 26.1329 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 429.6174 11.9362 431.7438 13.7375 431.7136 15.8296 432.0447 17.6645 431.4645 18.9102 429.1293 18.9659 427.1342 20.4521 426.2528 19.1618 423.8198 18.1036 420.9872 16.9827 423.9341 14.3368 428.4167 12.9232 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 452.5262 58.4915 453.2622 57.1437 455.1472 55.927 456.2236 54.6809 457.9798 56.118 459.0224 58.1467 460.3827 58.2886 462.2276 59.7929 462.6463 61.4409 463.385 63.8932 461.0639 64.4584 459.4911 65.7473 457.3909 64.7117 456.9724 62.4508 455.3782 61.8331 455.1073 60.0129 452.5482 59.7351 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 478.4183 87.4427 480.6696 88.6185 482.1732 90.3324 483.1285 92.3901 483.9311 94.0623 483.2568 95.544 481.9386 96.44 480.2941 95.1947 480.4793 93.7094 479.775 92.5358 478.7085 91.8452 479.4029 90.3613 478.7686 88.0795 Z"/>
</g>
<g id="region2" class="region2">
    <path class=" department" d="M 478.4183 87.4427 479.6502 85.7021 481.3607 85.0711 483.6499 84.1817 483.7384 81.6765 484.3432 84.611 485.065 89.4545 483.1285 92.3901 482.1732 90.3324 480.6696 88.6185 478.4183 87.4427 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 437.6653 51.8021 439.371 50.9384 440.8692 52.1508 443.4562 52.4909 445.7228 54.3116 446.1966 56.7834 446.64 59.1111 444.9765 59.5043 442.6142 58.8459 440.258 59.9059 438.2376 58.6126 437.0423 57.2996 436.5554 54.7754 437.8932 52.8581 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 433.758 70.9779 435.2287 71.0886 437.162 72.2244 437.9503 74.1845 440.1633 75.2612 438.0876 76.0434 436.9779 77.6842 434.687 78.0261 433.6605 77.2004 431.9298 75.3211 430.7492 73.2967 431.7347 71.7947 432.9276 71.0365 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 460.6571 51.9075 462.955 50.9984 466.4195 49.4937 466.7054 51.9559 467.7971 53.504 466.5054 54.8016 464.9088 55.1215 463.4959 55.4809 461.6047 55.7078 460.0987 54.7344 460.2216 52.3318 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 458.3984 56.9625 459.6249 54.6068 460.8188 55.1846 462.2511 56.166 464.7442 54.248 465.6504 55.8615 467.5361 56.5682 468.4242 58.5072 468.289 60.7216 466.7207 61.6568 464.2785 62.2283 462.1826 61.2955 462.2577 59.3245 460.3055 58.7154 458.7168 57.6942 Z"/>
</g>
<g id="region3">
    <path class=" department" d="M 465.2557 74.3626 467.3476 73.3578 465.6323 70.7821 466.9756 68.9609 469.0534 70.5975 471.64 70.9432 472.1881 72.5289 470.958 74.7311 469.396 75.3092 467.4337 76.7349 466.9327 76.092 465.2854 74.5744 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 437.663 77.8077 438.7068 75.7259 440.7532 75.2622 441.6241 74.1447 443.206 73.2337 445.2388 72.8912 446.8632 73.7264 448.3704 74.8843 446.6388 77.0071 442.4319 79.5769 440.0735 78.7085 438.9286 79.3736 437.7586 77.9017 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 434.3654 1.8687 435.653 4.2946 436.7338 5.6428 438.8183 6.1655 439.2633 6.9519 440.9816 7.794 440.9361 9.6822 441.2696 11.2982 439.6201 12.3256 438.6675 11.464 437.3267 11.2104 436.8922 10.2248 435.003 10.4122 433.5162 9.1426 430.9633 8.5997 431.0891 4.6234 433.4818 2.1348 Z M 440.5633 11.1756 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 429.6174 11.9362 431.7005 10.5094 432.0278 8.8814 434.1476 9.8979 436.0725 10.271 436.5662 10.8814 437.8461 11.4986 438.9723 11.9044 440.3934 12.174 441.6657 13.2059 441.4154 15.5894 439.7004 15.7526 438.2312 17.1233 436.4584 16.2431 434.061 15.7266 432.5297 15.2092 430.9319 12.8949 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 4.9388 303.7338 6.921 304.2409 7.6346 305.82 6.0686 306.3049 5.4592 304.9452 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 419.5989 76.3137 421.1413 77.1385 422.4772 78.2709 424.3064 79.195 423.6587 80.8511 424.5068 82.2884 423.3946 84.1458 421.7972 84.3563 419.5319 84.316 418.3644 82.3065 419.2665 80.5515 420.4633 78.5217 419.8128 76.6338 Z M 419.47 78.6936 Z M 419.3031 79.2132 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 435.2286 66.5512 437.1281 66.1642 438.0998 64.097 439.7147 64.4746 440.947 66.7911 441.5028 69.0117 442.5384 70.5055 442.6905 71.7414 443.0371 73.202 441.4368 74.0897 440.5053 75.1267 438.0734 74.3884 437.2284 72.5266 435.667 70.9921 434.0055 70.8182 433.0179 69.5168 433.0213 67.8075 435.1235 66.8225 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 411.7532 67.964 414.9873 68.2215 417.5128 69.6717 419.5371 70.9258 420.736 73.0077 418.9058 73.1782 418.6364 75.2804 417.9781 76.6108 415.9535 76.5864 413.8209 76.7885 412.3318 76.6605 410.4534 75.7114 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 409.9235 76.8016 412.4786 76.9821 414.4531 76.7004 416.4916 76.6841 418.3383 76.2781 419.8644 77.4136 419.9439 78.9456 418.9897 80.8891 418.1775 82.9473 416.4078 83.7708 415.0475 82.0307 412.3634 81.4171 410.3349 80.8304 409.6186 79.3485 408.4534 78.2061 Z M 419.47 78.6936 Z M 419.3031 79.2132 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 432.375 85.6787 435.3277 84.7612 437.5923 83.1646 440.2001 82.8807 441.6624 86.5781 439.6354 86.7822 437.755 87.6622 435.5668 86.9234 433.3677 86.7768 432.2887 85.7477 Z M 433.5293 86.7468 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 424.5268 55.9791 425.8347 53.8622 425.7891 52.7194 426.1013 50.638 428.0372 49.5192 430.0295 50.2592 430.5977 52.3241 430.7738 54.0158 432.2716 54.4878 433.1731 56.3362 431.2357 57.3184 428.993 58.1948 427.747 57.7041 425.5365 57.1796 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 415.4534 59.729 417.5249 61.0488 419.9864 61.8948 420.1884 64.2359 422.2032 64.5753 421.1929 65.44 420.5132 67.1395 419.7218 69.0453 418.7246 69.886 415.9208 68.5916 413.2763 68.3891 412.1453 66.1618 412.088 65.5808 412.4218 58.37 414.808 59.5588 415.7187 61.2803 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 426.1396 45.8403 427.432 43.8456 429.0271 42.6279 430.4516 41.0036 432.7537 41.5766 433.8467 42.4087 434.8158 44.1662 434.4298 46.1949 435.133 48.5902 433.0353 48.9577 431.226 49.0572 429.643 49.527 427.9596 48.5908 426.4209 47.1718 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 406.7982 43.0512 409.1892 44.554 409.9706 43.0819 410.9845 43.1507 413.4566 43.1462 415.284 45.117 416.0171 47.2571 416.0461 49.3729 415.2742 50.2146 413.6475 49.7601 411.4214 50.3187 409.0001 48.946 406.831 46.2757 Z M 403.9793 46.0692 Z M 404.6048 43.1013 404.6449 43.4542 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 420.2934 61.0291 421.9539 59.4095 423.5538 57.6907 424.5268 55.9791 426.1475 56.87 428.0385 57.9095 428.9376 59.1695 428.5858 60.8993 429.715 62.0762 429.9705 64.1076 428.6946 65.792 426.5428 66.3685 424.8823 65.9831 422.7582 66.1178 421.7894 64.3531 420.3857 63.0639 420.2807 61.4168 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 420.6228 41.7187 422.0742 42.6727 423.2758 43.931 424.9808 43.7806 426.5423 46.3435 427.4852 47.9047 427.9124 49.6415 426.0724 50.7695 424.6286 52.3029 423.2759 52.7055 421.7274 51.6816 421.3061 49.8257 420.1934 48.6127 419.812 47.0851 420.2091 45.1141 419.6201 43.2136 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 431.7125 79.1971 433.4814 80.7542 433.4569 83.0778 434.7707 84.4071 432.721 85.5797 430.5595 85.0198 428.9055 84.3438 426.3458 83.5235 427.156 81.6461 428.1679 80.5356 429.0507 79.9815 429.6418 79.0653 430.9392 79.302 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 440.8243 45.3854 443.1751 46.1971 444.6622 46.0473 445.5963 47.2739 447.0626 48.5011 446.4896 50.6331 446.0794 52.7531 444.8298 53.3029 441.8604 52.4678 440.012 51.4691 438.7891 51.2915 436.8296 50.3121 435.7458 48.7946 437.7851 47.875 438.227 46.4242 440.2856 45.4198 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 457.3646 17.901 459.4261 17.2127 460.5177 19.2338 460.8297 21.1342 460.9667 22.7048 462.7967 23.7572 463.9116 25.2627 466.1167 26.5103 467.8959 27.4041 466.9105 29.0685 464.8547 28.7923 462.9771 28.8836 461.246 29.6398 460.1889 28.6866 459.0095 27.3861 459.0938 25.6187 459.71 23.0607 459.222 21.4462 459.1858 19.394 457.6156 18.6864 Z M 457.0631 18.0187 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 460.2356 17.9074 462 17.8565 462.143 18.3795 464.3422 20.2568 465.4364 20.8587 466.7795 21.6943 468.2991 21.2866 470.7223 22.829 471.8837 23.5131 469.9515 22.5494 468.0965 24.4731 468.4158 24.6181 469.0728 26.8993 469.5753 27.391 467.8959 26.6539 466.1167 25.4837 463.9116 23.8149 462.7967 22.6838 460.9667 21.1724 460.8297 19.3298 460.5177 17.9074 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 433.7816 30.391 435.8285 30.175 437.3713 31.3275 438.7118 31.9162 440.846 32.1274 441.1778 33.888 440.5228 35.4715 440.1231 36.7636 439.5182 38.2355 437.5368 37.5938 435.2086 36.5575 432.8463 36.4391 431.0502 35.8857 430.5686 33.4839 432.1601 32.6458 433.5907 30.7067 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 472.0436 22.5091 474.3529 22.7946 475.3976 24.3115 473.1866 27.2878 472.0974 31.222 469.9855 30.5675 468.9442 30 468.9865 29.8568 468.3739 28.3217 469.5324 27.254 469.4948 25.0936 468.0924 24.6508 467.9467 23.2027 469.7061 23.5185 471.7561 23.2297 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 444.8769 45.8315 447.521 45.5693 447.5036 43.6145 448.5496 42.1482 449.9898 42.5219 451.7962 43.9282 454.5073 43.5292 456.3182 44.3008 456.6272 45.1458 457.1406 47.0201 456.2811 48.8205 453.7146 48.1817 452.328 51.4509 451.2753 50.4998 449.928 51.3737 447.8192 51.3493 447.2871 49.9683 446.4728 48.1885 445.0281 46.2832 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 440.1768 31.6466 440.92 29.665 443.4201 29.3361 444.842 30.7205 445.6234 31.8996 446.8115 33.5523 448.2924 33.935 449.2302 34.9356 448.9252 36.6259 448.2285 38.445 447.1359 39.6657 446.2201 39.5326 444.5447 38.3738 442.6175 38.4343 440.542 37.6589 439.6449 35.8244 440.6909 34.582 441.3049 33.0631 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 432.734 41.1572 434.8929 40.3719 435.4886 38.7223 436.0271 37.2677 438.2593 38.2254 440.0602 39.2903 440.8201 42.4381 440.8243 45.3854 438.7664 45.837 437.8098 47.1635 436.0889 48.2876 435.0666 48.2075 434.3122 45.9758 434.2992 44.0017 433.7934 42.0845 432.734 41.1572 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 443.8971 24.5988 445.017 22.6256 445.6891 21.4415 445.6467 19.5735 447.6618 18.9441 450.3716 20.1662 452.326 20.4429 454.1262 20.8918 454.2232 23.2875 453.4745 25.0406 453.3703 26.3997 452.2604 27.7828 449.5416 27.0223 447.5928 26.5774 445.81 27.9273 443.9266 26.7098 443.6027 25.3129 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 441.4101 15.718 441.4986 13.3724 442.9847 12.2604 445.6707 12.0653 447.9457 12.9299 448.8431 14.6663 448.062 16.531 447.6869 18.6165 445.746 19.461 445.5285 21.2708 444.5936 22.7185 444.0064 24.3982 442.7276 23.7522 441.0954 21.85 440.6936 21.1575 440.8613 20.1004 441.4974 18.5877 441.2411 16.5932 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 448.9706 13.0711 451.4424 12.7685 453.3142 11.4661 453.3706 13.4488 454.9612 15.354 456.2901 16.7061 455.5334 17.1635 454.8543 18.4907 454.1685 20.3818 452.2359 20.4742 450.2596 20.1617 447.6456 18.5145 448.1698 16.4631 448.9067 14.3718 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 437.7023 26.244 437.8419 24.0224 438.2361 22.025 440.2569 22.1708 442.1337 23.1592 443.6737 24.5545 443.3762 25.6235 444.2371 27.0827 443.2922 28.6097 441.5552 29.5158 440.4262 31.2174 438.3189 32.0654 437.2603 31.0126 437.039 29.3334 437.3409 27.3467 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 440.4426 37.6556 442.5421 38.3109 444.3539 38.3259 446.1202 39.5536 447.2107 39.6275 448.3336 40.9517 447.7579 42.4021 447.8657 44.3787 446.338 46.097 444.403 46.1574 442.9764 46.4693 440.9972 45.0919 440.7308 41.9673 440.1365 38.9338 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 434.4303 1.9175 437.5241 1 437.6416 1.2599 438.067 3.7174 439.829 5.1137 441.4766 4.2579 442.4845 6.3443 444.1596 7.3693 445.4226 9.4152 447.9191 9.2271 448.6206 10.1685 448.7075 12.1026 447.0147 12.3046 444.2971 12.0538 441.7401 12.4021 441.5746 10.308 441.0693 9.2282 440.4082 7.2132 439.4898 6.0076 437.8983 5.9222 436.1226 4.7541 434.9761 3.0133 Z M 440.5633 11.1756 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 395.4358 26.5805 396.1436 25.2021 398.1366 24.7602 399.212 25.4813 400.4007 26.0529 401.9322 28.1086 404.0733 26.6477 405.5595 27.1451 406.8672 27.8829 407.1233 29.0347 406.1489 30.3258 404.5138 31.9558 402.9544 32.5019 401.3777 32.1827 398.9778 31.4508 396.9351 31.6581 396.3477 30.7057 395.9459 28.1679 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 459.2826 74.9824 461.2262 75.4088 463.3867 74.8791 465.4387 74.7759 467.1416 76.1641 466.3059 77.9434 465.28 79.2181 464.5149 80.197 462.1956 80.734 460.4371 80.5959 459.6899 80.7371 459.3028 79.1011 459.1101 77.394 459.4747 75.1474 Z M 462.0396 81.725 Z M 463.8888 81.644 Z M 463.4586 81.7205 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 452.6824 51.473 453.9407 48.1625 456.2014 49.1565 457.7052 50.6133 459.3773 50.5766 461.9715 49.5028 460.9662 51.044 459.6458 52.781 459.4413 55.851 457.8864 56.2736 456.4653 54.3901 453.9228 55.0422 452.3394 53.6876 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 404.7436 31.9531 406.347 30.3536 407.0402 28.7614 406.6022 26.9277 408.9606 27.0865 410.8877 28.6559 412.9993 28.1229 412.8828 31.1751 412.9929 33.4907 411.9631 35.1349 409.4972 35.5349 407.3812 36.3828 405.8935 36.2454 405.9992 34.8831 404.8224 33.2158 Z M 406.6497 27.5163 406.321 26.9135 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 432.3575 15.169 433.8774 15.69 436.089 16.0869 438.0858 16.8628 439.5726 16.0717 441.2629 15.7197 441.2582 17.6857 441.0239 19.4857 440.409 20.8474 441.4019 21.1068 440.0864 22.2659 437.8283 22.2423 436.1713 21.3886 433.8566 21.2332 432.0174 20.8834 432.0435 18.8686 431.9433 17.4108 431.8704 15.437 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 420.7738 72.5506 422.8458 72.3294 424.7577 72.1631 425.5863 73.1015 426.727 74.3911 428.408 76.1812 427.1951 77.9088 425.401 77.8835 422.9466 78.6401 421.1879 77.6986 420.0328 76.1115 418.4739 75.6515 418.8439 73.7288 420.2973 72.9219 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 424.3752 78.8509 426.5873 78.1302 427.4315 76.8301 427.5503 75.5696 427.9037 74.1729 429.2056 73.7234 430.7492 73.2967 431.9298 75.3211 433.6605 77.2004 433.2446 78.0109 431.7828 79.1623 430.3479 79.2392 429.2926 79.3494 428.835 80.3848 427.3048 80.8078 426.2687 82.3522 424.7263 83.6142 423.472 84.5126 424.2298 82.6559 424.0856 81.0501 424.1383 79.5726 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 427.4766 68.8077 428.7671 69.7042 430.4955 69.802 432.0363 69.3759 433.373 70.0653 432.6649 71.1297 431.8164 71.9706 430.5904 73.2962 429.3981 73.9128 427.5885 74.1626 426.2826 73.2419 425.416 72.0781 426.2835 70.592 427.0186 68.898 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 427.5511 66.9198 429.0496 65.0129 429.8834 63.2973 431.683 62.8552 433.4937 63.3269 434.9333 65.0731 434.8214 66.9837 432.7364 67.8851 432.4148 69.2635 430.9505 70.1423 428.9709 70.0025 427.9462 68.8781 427.0067 67.1799 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 466.693 35.0983 467.8492 32.9263 469.0847 30.1518 471.2333 31.8947 471.5612 34.8313 471.2898 38.1631 469.3606 39.0677 467.885 37.4084 466.8088 35.4769 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 403.5875 38.8735 405.4181 38.2255 406.6051 36.68 408.996 36.2468 410.8862 35.0945 412.7753 37.1345 413.797 38.8444 411.0722 40.3114 411.8337 42.3362 411.0312 42.9535 410.1928 42.9515 409.6873 44.7123 407.0415 43.3512 405.6153 41.377 403.7659 40.7789 403.0664 39.5212 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 450.0184 51.0499 451.584 50.6085 452.6824 51.473 452.5703 54.2011 452.4107 55.8549 452.2621 57.3545 452.4044 58.1901 450.7116 57.2452 450.0287 55.0905 449.375 53.2549 450.2504 51.4538 Z M 452.6574 57.2153 453.9928 55.9212 455.1472 55.927 453.2622 57.1437 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 452.5509 53.8352 454.1719 55.0506 453.6215 56.5155 452.2621 57.3545 452.4107 55.8549 452.5703 54.2011 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 1 293.5229 1.0467 293.2283 2.8595 292.4083 3.7408 294.0598 3.197 295.686 1.9093 293.7367 1 293.5229 Z M 4.2055 295.8583 Z M 5.8236 293.374 Z M 2.0787 296.5199 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 414.2064 43.5847 416.4889 42.923 417.981 42.4715 419.673 43.146 420.1199 45.2072 419.7994 47.0173 420.1546 48.5368 421.1152 49.783 421.5784 51.6309 420.0996 52.6476 418.8154 52.7708 416.6365 51.8348 415.2742 50.2146 416.0461 49.3729 416.0171 47.2571 415.284 45.117 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 431.1718 22.2644 432.1613 21.2609 434.428 21.0618 436.6263 21.4911 437.6632 22.773 435.3918 23.8149 433.5808 22.806 431.7428 22.4846 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 414.5522 25.6228 416.7704 24.6187 418.814 24.7194 421.3077 23.846 422.8803 23.9964 424.6195 24.9649 425.6316 26.4216 426.6062 28.4628 425.5893 30.5506 423.6083 30.3995 422.2977 28.4123 420.2457 29.2613 418.7867 27.6172 417.0142 28.1966 415.2573 28.5711 415.0353 27.2934 414.5522 25.6228 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 412.6802 19.4895 416.4796 19.478 420.8291 19.1945 422.4696 20.1723 423.0369 21.8039 423.1881 23.39 421.2431 23.6621 418.6746 24.6465 416.5263 24.6648 414.6115 25.4893 412.3932 24.864 413.5399 23.5778 414.2418 21.7303 412.6902 20.3288 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 445.3151 53.8776 446.0009 52.1044 446.778 50.773 448.7943 51.2948 450.1432 51.4183 449.5101 53.1478 449.9464 54.9139 450.5952 57.1185 452.2941 58.1191 451.6258 59.8892 449.6397 59.8158 448.1229 59.4011 446.6957 59.4454 446.4464 56.9478 445.4976 54.4562 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 419.8851 29.4185 421.8279 28.4951 423.6007 30.1988 425.9805 31.6335 425.8985 33.2421 425.2215 35.2521 424.0522 36.6783 422.4418 37.3934 420.3247 37.1069 418.8986 36.3916 417.4337 35.3036 418.2056 33.6542 418.7453 32.0584 419.1914 29.8381 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 412.6802 19.4895 414.0485 21.2167 414.2781 22.8169 412.8558 24.3097 413.7954 25.2477 415.1239 26.4335 413.7166 28.0994 411.4354 28.2234 409.7829 27.3208 410.8062 26.4015 409.6533 23.6744 408.9856 20.3765 407.4831 17.6518 407.7708 15.6493 410.8232 15.7129 411.9997 18.378 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 431.1718 22.2644 433.0218 22.8668 435.2205 23.5875 434.8432 25.6168 434.066 27.3001 432.685 28.5466 431.1185 26.488 430.8452 24.229 430.3435 22.5363 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 422.2668 18.6055 424.9389 18.8502 426.3066 19.8127 428.1299 19.5239 430.2711 18.3803 432.2447 19.7915 431.3137 21.9264 430.1707 23.1837 429.4561 24.9651 427.8455 25.5984 425.9601 26.3806 425.2049 25.2718 423.1097 24.2385 422.8317 22.3287 422.4233 20.4649 422.2715 18.8098 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 425.7934 26.4609 427.6397 25.5778 429.5159 25.2978 430.6932 24.0435 431.1907 26.2711 432.4761 28.561 433.7043 29.9662 432.9094 32.3409 431.0719 32.9962 429.3734 33.737 427.8022 32.4874 425.9633 32.2611 425.4735 30.0329 426.821 27.9686 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 395.4358 26.5805 395.8357 29.0109 396.2481 31.204 395.3344 32.7057 397.25 33.7423 396.2997 35.5217 393.5945 34.5243 392.0263 34.8312 390.5979 35.2144 389.0684 33.154 389.8099 32.4287 390.8722 31.2093 388.9329 30.6598 390.2326 30.3465 390.6055 29.9783 388.865 29.8728 387.9749 28.5159 389.3061 27.2035 391.2585 26.6831 393.4506 26.5369 395.5372 26.2455 Z M 385.3845 28.7331 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 456.7098 37.2858 458.6761 36.4895 459.506 34.772 460.6133 33.9601 462.4459 33.9568 464.961 33.89 466.0872 36.0871 465.6455 37.7469 464.1342 38.4019 462.4956 39.1378 460.7257 39.9839 458.5231 40.7957 457.0931 39.1408 457.4129 37.2583 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 449.3756 34.058 451.1152 33.259 453.0118 34.1655 453.6707 35.7314 455.6023 36.9209 457.537 37.7784 457.1687 39.2522 457.4343 41.1671 456.3207 43.188 453.456 43.6823 451.4104 43.6656 449.742 42.3398 448.2461 40.7638 448.1532 38.3149 448.945 36.544 449.1849 34.8427 Z M 448.6237 41.8505 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 49.8852 389.5818 51.6507 388.1912 52.6795 385.5686 53.2846 383.0407 54.0343 380.8604 52.6847 379.3668 51.2866 376.8834 50.9913 373.7095 51.5038 370.5211 53.8025 367.124 57.6028 367.631 61.6025 368.8901 64.5697 371.5096 65.9875 372.4371 68.0221 374.6479 69.51 375.6912 68.7535 379.1508 66.9484 381.74 65.2063 384.4125 63.9372 387.4299 63.1687 389.0111 61.0517 390.6729 59.0047 389.8521 55.779 389.7276 54.217 390.4329 51.4925 390.4291 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 411.855 35.232 412.8631 33.4312 412.9744 31.2674 412.9453 28.3299 414.9817 28.5658 416.6587 28.2631 418.4841 27.9353 419.9034 29.1046 419.2204 31.1257 418.105 32.8503 417.7513 34.5383 417.1048 35.6473 414.8974 35.7256 412.5426 35.5793 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 411.8068 35.5646 414.1853 35.5864 416.4532 35.7563 418.3213 36.1416 419.8131 36.7888 421.513 37.3449 421.2573 39.8956 420.0128 42.1026 418.4718 42.3613 416.8498 42.5523 414.8263 43.403 412.4243 42.6272 411.6017 40.4412 413.663 39.631 413.087 37.3321 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 425.9633 32.2611 427.8022 32.4874 429.3734 33.737 430.8019 34.1123 431.8772 36.1163 433.6996 36.6864 435.1613 37.2758 435.217 39.2991 433.9711 40.6864 431.8262 40.6984 429.0961 41.1646 427.7355 39.171 426.841 37.1232 425.0939 36.5153 424.9947 35.4375 425.813 33.4487 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 419.5576 53.4984 421.1804 52.1827 423.4852 52.4609 424.8392 52.1098 426.5357 53.0969 425.5515 54.994 424.1023 56.5821 423.1239 58.2096 421.6864 60.2765 420.0119 60.5957 418.4785 59.6062 418.5268 57.8568 417.4016 56.0712 418.8931 55.3622 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 421.8173 37.2602 423.3562 36.9531 425.7234 36.554 427.1663 37.2679 427.6852 40.0654 429.5052 41.9955 428.1375 42.9532 427.1252 45.7504 425.0634 44.137 423.8384 43.7882 422.2813 42.8097 420.8145 41.9917 421.2996 39.7187 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 412.5818 50.216 414.2369 50.0018 415.9919 51.6274 418.0121 52.3941 419.2628 53.9365 417.8064 55.3408 417.4464 56.9346 418.5425 58.8591 418.9301 59.947 420.2649 61.1212 418.5918 61.8407 416.3843 59.9968 414.2086 57.7566 411.9224 56.1821 412.95 53.8141 412.5825 52.2016 412.6432 50.5956 Z M 409.6581 50.8102 411.5647 51.5882 Z M 410.6732 52.7455 412.1477 54.8484 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 452.8235 60.0193 455.0566 60.3083 455.2185 62.118 457.2246 62.1976 457.4426 64.9293 459.7838 65.7472 458.6698 67.6048 457.3177 68.3548 458.4184 69.5368 458.7696 70.9851 456.8333 70.95 455.3133 69.65 452.9128 70.1971 452.0889 68.1991 452.5385 65.2933 453.3315 63.3122 452.8991 61.114 Z M 453.2881 69.1262 454.4142 68.6926 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 459.6095 65.6845 461.1668 64.4337 463.3747 63.4431 463.2486 61.7211 465.2295 61.8284 466.2794 63.9358 467.9439 65.4688 466.1698 66.9507 463.6553 67.7006 462.2913 68.4306 460.6614 68.6234 459.9994 70.0692 458.7616 70.3866 457.5217 69.194 457.4261 67.7366 458.5159 66.2466 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 453.8389 20.614 454.8319 18.7676 455.2811 17.2224 457.0565 16.8453 457.5597 18.8214 459.1693 19.5566 459.3261 21.4865 459.605 23.2139 459.0146 25.7033 459.0245 27.5796 458.1126 28.8363 455.7919 27.9499 454.1364 26.7131 453.5942 24.7703 454.4177 23.1363 453.9749 20.6234 Z M 457.0631 18.0187 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 444.3776 26.9806 446.2047 28.0568 447.813 26.3456 449.7406 27.209 451.6732 28.5689 453.1612 30.2928 452.162 32.2939 450.9967 33.6112 448.9386 33.6179 447.3323 33.9917 446.2341 32.7221 444.8348 31.3526 444.103 29.6624 443.4168 27.8705 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 451.9348 27.8844 453.1067 26.4355 454.3962 27.051 456.5377 28.3843 457.3055 29.724 458.8191 31.8385 459.4586 33.5391 459.221 34.836 458.4522 36.5689 456.487 37.3773 454.5073 36.601 453.9595 35.0062 452.759 33.2455 453.0683 31.5943 452.5153 29.578 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 457.3612 29.0197 459.297 28.2982 460.2449 29.1794 461.5406 29.4098 463.6194 29.1473 465.353 28.8899 467.796 28.4052 468.4807 29.4531 468.9442 30 469.0847 30.1518 467.8492 32.9263 466.693 35.0983 464.3802 34.3528 462.0468 33.7271 460.5314 33.513 459.1761 32.7994 459.0495 31.1347 457.1664 29.4357 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 451.7956 69.8364 453.319 69.935 455.1869 70.162 457.5603 71.296 457.8972 73.7931 458.9613 75.3044 454.5186 74.3822 452.9053 72.5025 452.1774 70.567 Z M 453.2881 69.1262 454.2348 69.3249 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 440.4867 66.2728 441.4585 63.8575 443.128 63.2578 444.6377 64.0613 446.2724 65.2886 447.0824 67.0172 447.0018 69.3989 446.6803 70.9879 444.7511 71.2931 442.7562 70.4933 441.5155 69.2687 441.1236 66.9591 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 457.5603 71.296 458.6359 70.6047 459.7906 69.9246 460.8322 68.5099 462.4265 68.6281 463.7467 67.9375 466.24 66.8264 467.1654 67.0841 466.6551 69.1106 465.7724 71.203 466.9054 73.3464 464.9295 74.2676 462.7035 74.2984 460.6667 75.028 458.6339 74.1061 457.6846 72.4687 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 396.0776 31.4193 398.2746 31.7685 399.9918 31.6846 402.203 32.4719 403.6426 31.552 405.2033 32.4856 406.0355 33.9719 406.1105 35.705 405.9935 37.3867 404.5776 38.7006 403.5314 38.2316 401.3186 38.4622 402.0095 37.4484 400.5509 37.4421 399.5261 37.6453 398.9583 37.9803 397.3492 36.1022 396.8038 34.9599 395.9334 33.4575 395.1964 31.7728 Z M 398.1164 39.6378 398.5387 40.3758 Z M 396.4177 36.8626 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 458.9134 40.7047 461.1169 40.032 462.8581 38.9145 464.4853 38.3846 465.9857 37.786 467.1135 38.41 468.1622 39.9142 466.7818 41.7037 464.3802 43.6883 462.8756 46.4081 462.1861 45.9039 460.9374 44.001 459.282 42.9518 459.0585 41.1544 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 455.9031 43.5505 457.2876 41.5273 458.5231 40.7957 459.456 42.6064 460.4261 43.4925 461.986 45.1304 462.0188 47.8503 460.2403 50.3955 458.2307 50.2799 456.7316 49.6361 456.6028 48.1023 456.6217 46.0128 456.9265 44.677 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 446.4573 65.331 448.1762 64.0376 449.7001 62.632 450.4877 61.7367 450.6503 61 450.6278 60.8299 452.3012 59.4645 452.9194 61.3275 453.2891 63.7326 452.6268 65.6945 451.9054 68.3515 450.432 69.5851 448.5969 69.429 447.6305 68.4146 446.6716 66.559 Z"/>
    <path class=" department" d="M 443.1418 70.7763 444.9425 70.7183 447.1037 70.7785 446.7668 68.5792 447.779 68.9497 449.2745 69.7862 451.0624 69.3269 452.1817 71.3885 452.407 73.1003 451.01 75.1463 449.9872 76.5821 448.1422 77 448.332 76.791 448.1779 74.8645 446.6915 73.5431 444.8368 73.1737 442.9846 73.0276 442.5752 71.7141 Z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Add an extra path that follows the border and colour it as you wish.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the answer, but paths in the source file are very long, it would take me ages to make a path for each region of France. Maybe there's some tool to generate an external path for a group, not sure about that.

Comment: Perhaps [svgdotjs/svg.js](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js) could generate external path from group paths ?